# Pandas divide entries of a column by entries from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes - A and B. A contains weekly sales data for various stores, departments indexed by a key `Store_Dept_Date` (eg. `2_12_2010-04-03` )while B contains corresponding Consumer Price Index (CPI) for given store and date indexed as `Store_Date` for e.g. `2_2010-04-03` .

```
> A.columns  
> Out [ ] : Index([u'Store', u'Dept', u'Date', u'Weekly_Sales'], dtype='object')

> B.columns  
> Out [ ] : Index([u'Store', u'Date', u'CPI'], dtype='object')
```

I want to normalize the weekly sales given in A by dividing each row of A by corresponding CPI value given in B.

Currently I am trying this:

```
for ix,row in A.iterrows():
  f_index = str(row['Store']) + "_" + row['Date']
  A.ix[ix,'Weekly_Sales'] = row['Weekly_Sales']/ B.ix[f_index,'CPI']
```

A contains 421570 rows. My program takes forever to run. Whats the correct and efficient way of doing it?

Comment: `A.set_index(['Store', 'Date'])['Weekly_Sales'] / B.set_index(['Store', 'Date'])['CPI']`. This works best if `A` or `B` should just always be indexed, as the indexes will help other operations too.

Comment: The data frames A & B are already indexed on a different key as described in the question. Why is my program so slow? The solution given by @slushy works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The DataFrames' **merge** method should be faster even though it copies data. You can set the flag `copy=False` to minimize unnecessary copying.

If there is one date in B for every date in A, then you can do:

```
C = A.merge(B, on=['Store', 'Date'], copy=False)
C['Normalized_Sales'] = C.Weekly_Sales / C.CPI
```